# NetBeans 15 / 16 Java Compiler Failure

Tags: java, netbeans

The problem is already reported at [NullPointerException in compiler, Java files with red error badges can't be run](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/4766)
but I need to ask it here as a question because the more than 6 weeks old bug record does not have any response, no workaround. I really need to know how to get this problem solved, a type of problem that I have not seen before to that extent. I have been using NetBeans with Java for decades. Any suggestions, including non-technical are highly appreciated. More specifically, I would like to know how I can help the NetBeans team to pinpoint the error in nb-javac. Such issues are normally resolved with finer logging levels that would identify at least some offending files being processed. A NullPointerException without context is very difficult to analyze.

Comment: Without a [mre] it may be very difficult to help you. (Same goes for the NetBeans team, I expect - although they may have more insight into the logs than most of the rest of us do.)

Comment: Also, it helps if you can make your question self-contained (one which can include - but does not rely on - [external links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/671985).)

Comment: My only suggestion is: Try changing your compilation support to earlier versions of Java - e.g. for Maven, `<maven.compiler.source>` and `<maven.compiler.target>`. Try Java 11 and then Java 13 - and re-work any code which relies on newer or preview-only features. You may find NetBeans is not handling a more recent language enhancement correctly (for example, I know it does not currently handle all features of the newer switch expressions with lambda-style code blocks). A long shot, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: I have maven compiler setting 1.8. Maven javac works fine. NetBeans uses a different compiler that creates the errors. And when I "run" the classes, then NetBeans fails on the results of that compiler and not on the results of the maven build which is actually successful. It's not a user error. It is an internal NetBeans error.

Comment: I have tried to make a minimum reproducible test case because that makes sense. This was a lot of work. When the test case gets smaller then the error disappears. But in any case, this does not seem to be the problem. The problem is that the NetBeans team is not approachable. Therefore I cannot find out what they need and what I can do at my end to help them.

Comment: It's inappropriate to post that the NetBeans team _"is not approachable"_ on SO. Regardless, they asked for your project to attempt to reproduce the problem, and you refused! What more can you reasonably expect them to do if you won't help them? And on top of that, you are using an operating system (Windows 7) for which support ended nearly 3 years ago, you are compiling to Java 8 for which active support ended 10 months ago, and you are running NetBeans 15 with Java 14 which is not formally supported. Try to reproduce your problem with a cleaner and more stable environment.

Comment: Consider trying to reproduce your problem using NetBeans 12 (which offers LTS) instead. It also supports LTS release Java 11, and also Java 8. Since Maven is building your code for 1.8 it can't matter that you are losing new features provided in JDK 14 anyway. Alternatively, try running NetBeans 15 with JDK 11 rather than JDK 14, since JDK 11 is formally supported. That may not solve your problem, but it will only take a few minutes to find out either way.

Comment: Update: NetBeans 12 is not an option and I have tried JDK 11 with NetBeans 15 and NetBeans 16. Apart from the fact that I cannot find out whether NetBeans 12 has the problem, I am not interested in NetBeans 12 because it is too buggy. Please see my more detailed comments in the github issue

Comment: So: you won't give the NetBeans Team access to your project, you won't consider using older versions of NetBeans, you are running a JDK that is not formally supported by NetBeans, and you have not provided any relevant new information here - all you have done is link to your NetBeans bug report. Your post here is not even a valid Stack Overflow question since all it does to link to somewhere else. Update your question to show all relevant information in the question body, and show the stack trace generated when using JDK 11 rather than JDK 14. And NetBeans 12.6 doesn't support JDK 8, use 12.5.

Comment: Since when does NetBeans require that I publish proprietary software on their public web site to fix their bugs? I consider using older versions as long as they are not broken. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-6089
Nobody told me to NOT to use 12.6. Smokescreen. The NetBeans team has so far not even looked at the crash. I cannot see any comments regarding it.
All the claims here regarding my environment being unsupported are invalid because all my configurations are completely valid and supported. javac works but nb-javac breaks. It's that simple.

Comment: Windows 7 is no longer supported by Microsoft. But all Java development kits that I am aware of support Windows 7 i.e. can be installed on it. Windows 7 has not changed. Any such Java platform should refuse to run on Windows 7 if it lacks the required features which is not the case.

Comment: Your question _"I would like to know how I can help the NetBeans team to pinpoint the error in nb-javac"_ is way off topic for Stack Overflow. And regarding _"Nobody told me to NOT to use 12.6. Smokescreen."_, [the 12.6 Release Notes explicitly tell you not to](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb126/nb126.html): _"The Apache NetBeans 12.6 binary releases **require JDK 11+**, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17."_ Some smokescreen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Maven project, the bug is most likely caused by a missing package statement in package-info.java file in the main sources. This condition is not reported by javac, and it is not reported by nb-javac.

Instead, the error occurs away from the culprit,  in test source files.

So the solution is to add a package statement to package-info.java